# Join a table based on first table's content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to come up with a query where a 3rd table will join another two.  The problem is there are different versions of this first table and I need the query to look at a column in table 1 and then choose the correct table to join but the resulting query must return all rows in table 1 just join an extra table 3 to specific rows which meet the WHERe clause.  *Is this even possible?*

**Example:**

Table 1 = User

Table 2 = Banners

Table 3 = UserSettings OR AdminSettings OR Nothing

***Query would say...***

```
WHERE User.rank='admin' LEFT JOIN AdminSettings

WHERE User.rank='user' LEFT JOIN UserSettings
```

My current query is this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users as U WHERE U.user_id = :id ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN Banners as B ON U.banner_id = B.banner_id ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN AdminSettings ON U.server_id = AdminSettings.user_id WHERE U.rank='Admin' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Problem is that it only shows rows that have User.rank='admin' and does not show the rows where User.rank='user' rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a IF clause in the fields list, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT field1, field2, field3, IF(User.rank = 'admin', A.field, B.field)";
$query .= " FROM Users as U";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN Banners as B ON U.banner_id = B.banner_id";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN AdminSettings as A ON U.server_id = A.user_id";
$query .= " LIMIT 1";
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Join `table3` twice and use `CASE` within the select statement

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.*
        CASE WHEN a.rank = 'admin' 
            THEN c.user_ID                     -- gets value from AdminSettings
            ELSE d.user_ID                     -- gets value from UserSettings
        END as ColName1,
        CASE WHEN a.rank = 'admin' 
            THEN c.colName                     -- gets value from AdminSettings
            ELSE d.colName                     -- gets value from UserSettings
        END as ColName2
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN banners b
            ON a.banner_id = b.banner_id
        LEFT JOIN  AdminSettings c
            ON a.server_ID = c.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN UserSettings d
            ON a.server_ID = d.user_ID
```